# Django SELECT COUNT(*) as "__count" for every query

Tags: django, postgresql, django-rest-framework

I'm currently in the process of optimizing my Django app, which is acting as an API for my front-end with the Django Rest Framework.  While running my server in debug mode, I've noticed that every time a queryset gets executed, there's a query run right before it that always looks like this:

```
SELECT COUNT('*') AS "__count" FROM "table_name WHERE ..."
```

The ... part always mirrors the query that returns the objects that I want.  I'm unsure if this is only run in debug, something that the `QuerySet` object does innately, or an error with my code.  Would appreciate some insight as to why this is happening and if it's something I need to worry about

Comment: Do you have some debug tools installed like `django-debug-toolbar`?

Comment: Yes, but it isn't showing any of these `count(*)` queries.  Just the debug output in my terminal

Comment: Sorry, I'm totally wrong, they are showing up in the toolbar

Comment: What is the API request that causes the query, and the content of the response. Is the `count(*)` required for pagination?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This occurs in Django Rest Framework when you are using paging on a list view:

- One query to fetch the data for your current page.
- A second query to calculate the total number of records for the same queryset.

Comment: You're right, if I remove pagination, this will go away.  Thanks for helping me figure this out!